# Google Cloud Storage npm dependency issue

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-storage, npm-install

I am trying to upload a file to a Google Storage bucket through my front end. To do this I executed npm install --save @google-cloud/storage. But now when I npm run dev, I get 3 warnings.

These dependencies were not found:

- fast-crc32c in ./node_modules/hash-stream-validation/index.js
- request in ./node_modules/retry-request/index.js
- worker_threads in ./node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save fast-crc32c request worker_threads

But, when I run "npm install worker_threads" it returns
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: worker_threads@latest

How am I supposed to get this module and why is it required for Google Cloud Storage? Sorry if this is dumb or obvious.

Comment: What version of Node.js do you use?

Comment: Did you solve this? I think the problem is, that worker_threads are not supported in a browser environment, but only in node.js.